# Different size images adjust on one another in html css bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to create a page like this "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny4ty.jpg". Currently I got this "https://i.stack.imgur.com/eezxX.jpg". But in this approach I cant get the result as I want.

I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny4ty.jpg
Current: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eezxX.jpg

I have tried this code Currently.

```css
#box-image-div{
  /* Prevent vertical gaps */
  line-height: 0;

  -webkit-column-count: 20;
  -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
  -moz-column-count:    20;
  -moz-column-gap:      0px;
  column-count:         20;
  column-gap:           0px;  
}

#box-image-div img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-image-div">
    <img class="box-image" src="http://sty1.stallyons.com/advertising/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/112.png">
    <img class="box-image" src="http://sty1.stallyons.com/advertising/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/118.png">
    <img class="box-image" src="http://sty1.stallyons.com/advertising/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/113.png">
    <img class="box-image" src="http://sty1.stallyons.com/advertising/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/115.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I would say you are almost there. Maybe setting width values gets you the desired result

Comment: I dont think so. I have created column in css which is not a correct way.

Comment: Well to be honest bro I think it would be more practical to just use a collage instead of css. Because the thing you desire requires a large amount of code if you want the exact thing.

Comment: The effect you are after it is called: **Masonry** effect or layout. Use [masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) javascript library or google for a pure css solution

Comment: Try following this article by [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_grid_responsive). It creates collage in css with `css-flex`

Comment: Have a look at this image:  https://imgur.com/a/PS0U15Q. In this image you can see different width and heights but the thing is all images stack with each other. and there is no white spacing. I know about masonry. But in this case its not suitable I think.

Answer (score 0):

That image that you use as an example is from milliondollarscript, which if is not opensource, is available to download. 
If you want exactly that, see how they do it here:
https://gitlab.com/MillionDollarScript/MillionDollarScript